# Creating button with Flask in Python

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I'm using Flask to integrate a webpage into a project. However I can't get the buttons on the webpage to do anything. I'm not sure if its a result of the html or python.

The python

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'THING1':
            print ("THING1")
        elif request.form['submit_button'] == 'THING2':
            print ("THING2")
        elif request.form['submit_button'] == 'THING3':
            print ("THING3")
        elif request.form['submit_button'] == 'THING4':
            print ("THING4")
        else:
            pass # unknown
        return render_template('index.html', **templateData)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

And the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to Ben's Online Coffee Machine!!</h1>
<p>Please select your preference</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="THING1">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="THING2">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="THING3">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="THING4">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need a `<form>` element around your buttons.

Comment: That has managed to get a response from the buttons but it is not running the print statement like it was meant to

Comment: Can you update the question with your current HTML?